# Debian signature error

Tags: debian, apt

I am getting the following error when trying to update. This started when I added i386

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease: Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_bullseye_InRelease into data and signature failed
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease: Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/deb.debian.org_debian-security_dists_bullseye-security_InRelease into data and signature failed
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease: Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_bullseye-updates_InRelease into data and signature failed
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye/InRelease  Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_bullseye_InRelease into data and signature failed
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/dists/bullseye-security/InRelease  Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/deb.debian.org_debian-security_dists_bullseye-security_InRelease into data and signature failed
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bullseye-updates/InRelease  Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_bullseye-updates_InRelease into data and signature failed
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: You may want to show what you added and what your list of repositories looks like now.

Comment: Having same issue when installing a certain docker image.